# How to get filtered object length

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to show that there is no data to display when the size of filtered object is zero. Is there any way to check its size after calling filter method?

```
this.state.items
.filter(item => {
    // filter code
})
.map(item => {
    // display data
})
```

For example, this.state.items has ten items and becomes zero after passing through filter method. I'd like to display the message at this point.

Answer (score 0):

First store the filtered data in a variable:

```
let filteredData = this.state.items
                         .filter(item => {
                              // filter code
                          });
```

Now `filteredData` will contain the filtered data, now you can check the length of this variable and `return` 'No Data Found' if `length = 0`, Use either `ternary operator`:

```
return filteredData.length ? 

               filteredData.map(item => {
                    // display data
               })

               :

               <div>No data found </div>;
```

Or you can use `if-else` condition also:

```
if(filteredData.length)
      filteredData.map(item => {
         // display data
      })
else
   <div>No data found </div>
```

Comment: r u facing any issue in this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const filteredData = this.state.items((items) => //filter code);
return filteredData.count()
   ? filteredData.map(item => //data);
   : <div>No Data found </div>
```

Try this one with immutable object.